# c++ recursively nested types and name injection

Tags: c++, c++11, nested, code-injection, typename

I tried googling this with no luck, so I'm trying here.

I have a couple of classes, each of which defines a member `struct foo`. This member type `foo` can itself inherit from one of the former classes, hence obtaining a member type `foo` itself.

I want to access the nested `foo` types using template metaprogramming (see below), but c++ name injection introduces problems, as the upper `foo` type name gets injected into the lower `foo` type, and the upper one gets resolved when I want to access the lower, say using `A::foo::foo`.

Here is an example:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

struct A;
struct B;

struct A {
    struct foo;
};

struct B {
    struct foo;
};

struct A::foo : B { };
struct B::foo : A { };

// handy c++11 shorthand
template<class T>
using foo = typename T::foo;

static_assert( std::is_same< foo< foo< A > >, foo< B > >::value, 
               "this should not fail (but it does)" );

static_assert( std::is_same< foo< foo< A > >, foo< A > >::value, 
               "this should fail (but it does not)" );
```

FYI, I'm implementing function derivatives, `foo` is the derivative type. The above situation happens e.g. with sin/cos.

TLDR: how do i get `foo<foo<A>>` to be `foo<B>`, not `foo<A>` ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really an automatic solution but solves the problem. Your
types provide a typedef to the base class, absence/presence of this
typedef is detected through SFINAE and the nested foo is found either
through the base or through normal look-up.

You can probably automate the `has_base` to check a list of known
bases with `is_base_of` if you need more automation.

```
#include <type_traits>
template <typename T>
struct has_base
{
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no[2];

    template <typename C>
    static yes& test(typename C::base*);

    template <typename>
    static no& test(...);

    static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};

struct A {
    struct foo;
};

struct B {
    struct foo;
};

struct A::foo : B { typedef B base; };
struct B::foo : A { typedef A base; };

template<typename T, bool from_base = has_base<T>::value >
struct foo_impl {
  typedef typename T::base::foo type;
};

template<typename T> 
struct foo_impl<T, false> {
  typedef typename T::foo type;
};

template<typename T>
using foo = typename foo_impl<T>::type;

static_assert( std::is_same< foo< foo<A> >::, foo< B > >::value, 
               "this should not fail (but it does)" );

static_assert( std::is_same< foo< foo< A > >, foo< A > >::value, 
               "this should fail (but it does not)" );
int main()
{

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I had something similar in mind, but was kind of hoping I could avoid defining the member base type for each derived type... 

Thanks a lot anyways !

Comment: @MaximeTournier As I said: If the list of bases is fixed, you can handle them automatically. In the face of multiple inheritance this gets pretty weird.

Comment: Got it, but the list of bases is sadly not fixed :-/

Comment: @MaximeTournier So maybe you would be better of with a classic traits solution. Where the traits have to be specialized if required.

Comment: i end up accessing foo using traits classes (to be fully generic), but i also wanted a default trait implementation that spares me the burden of specializing the trait class each time :-)